# VSCode editor.language.brackets in Elixir

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, brackets, elixirls

After looking at different issues and conversations, I can't figure out how to configure VSCode to handle Elixir `do...end`, `do:` and `fn...end` as matching brackets.

I tried this configuration (in `settings.json`):

```
    "editor.language.brackets": [
        ["do", ":"],
        ["do", "end"],
        ["fn", "end"]
    ],
```

But then `do` matches the first `:` (which happens quite a lot with atoms)
I tried different others as:

- `["do:", " "]` but VSCode does not seem to handle whitespace as a char to match
- `[", do", ":"]` but then again, no success

Is there a way to handle that properly?

Links of issues/discussions:

- https://github.com/elixir-lsp/vscode-elixir-ls/issues/46
- https://github.com/elixir-lsp/vscode-elixir-ls/issues/344